# RoR - Give 'user' one, or many, standard 'goals' using [has_many] or [belongs_to]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Here is my Users model: ../db/migrate/

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Here is my Goals model: ../db/migrate/

```
class CreateGoals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :goals do |t|
      t.string :choice
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

What I am trying to accomplish is giving a user one, or many, goals. These are not unique goals, but five predetermined things such as ABCD or E that any other user can also have just as well.

I've tried to implement belongs_to and has_many right above `def change` but to no avail - every rake db:migrate has been unsuccessful.

Thank you for any help you can provide, it is always much appreciated.

Comment: Have you added belongs_to relationship in Goal model and has_many to User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These are not unique goals, but five **predetermined** things such as ABCD or E that any other user can also have just as well.

This would lend itself perfectly to [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_goals
  has_many :goals, through: :user_goals
end

#app/models/user_goal.rb
class UserGoal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :goal

  validates :goal, uniqueness: { scope: :user } #-> only unique entries
end

#app/models/goal.rb
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_goals
  has_many :users, through: :user_goals
end
```

This way, each `User` can have any one of the pre-determined goals:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users #-> url.com/users/:user_id/edit

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = User.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    @user.update user_params
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(goal_ids: [])
  end
end

#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :goal_ids, Goal.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

The migration would include:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true

    create_table :goals do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :user_goals do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :goal
      t.string :choice
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Goal
  belongs_to :user # define relation
end

class User
  has_many :goals  # define relation
end

class CreateGoals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :goals do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, null: false # <====== add user_id to goal
      t.string :choice
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```